# Image map no longer clickable

Tags: html

I am creating an image map of a universe. When you click on an galaxy or cluster it takes you to another image map of each of the planets. I left the code alone for several months when I came back to it the image map no longer sent me into another image.

I am using the same computer and methods I have used before. I am not sure what's causing the issue.

```
`<!Doctype>
 <html>
 <body>
 <img src="Universe_Map_2.0.png" usemap="Universemap">
 <map name="Universemap">
 <area shape="Circle" coords="729,760,5" href="Omega_Cluster_2.0.html">
 </map>
 </body>
 </html>`
```

I expect to be able to click on the image and it pulls up the new image.

Comment: What happens when you click on the `<area>`? nothing?

Comment: Nothing. The cursor no longer changes to the Clickable version and it does not allow me to click it.

Comment: Should still work, looking [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp). Only difference I can see is you have `usemap="Universemap"` vs. `usemap="#Universemap"`. Perhaps you can try it in another browser?

Comment: The lack of # was the only change needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to prepend the name of your map with a # in the `usemap` attribute. `<img ... usemap="#Universemap">`

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>

<body>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" usemap="#Universemap">
  <map name="Universemap">
 <area shape="Circle" coords="124,58,8" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/sun.htm">
 </map>
</body>

</html>
```